# Delay function onkeyup not preserving this.value

Tags: jquery

i have several texarea boxes generated with a loop in php (from mysql). Each textarea was saving it values in the db with the onchange event. I decided that a better way to save it is onkeyup, with a delay but i have problema passing this.value, it return undefined.

Here's the code:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="disgnostic<?php echo $orden;?>"
 onkeyup="delay(function(){userAction('update_diag', '<?php echo $orden;?>', this.value);}, 1500)">
<?php echo $r['diagnostico']; ?>
</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var delay = function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    }  
}();
```

All works ok, only this.value return undefied. Without the dalay it works OK!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine, apart from the context. Changing the onkeyup function this way solves your problem

```
onkeyup="delay(function(){userAction('update_diag', '<?php echo $orden;?>', this.value);}.bind(this), 1500)"
```

Notice the *bind* on your anonymous onkeyup function, that hard binds the context of the function

*this* context can be confusing in JavaScript and I recommend [this chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#chapter-2-this-all-makes-sense-now) to understand the nuances of *this*

Answer (score 0):

When you call the delay function you are loosing the context for this, you should do somehing like this:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textOne"
onkeyup="delay(function(){alert(this.value);}.bind(this), 1500)">
</textarea>
```

And on js:

```
var delay = function(){
  var timer = 10;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  }  
}();
```